# How do you determine 32 or 64 bit architecture of Windows using Java?

Tags: java, windows, x86, 64-bit

How do you determine 32 or 64 bit architecture of Windows using Java?

Comment: Why would you want to know this? Java is supposed to run the same on any OS for which there is a JVM - your Java program shouldn't care if it's running on a 32-bit or 64-bit OS.

Comment: @Jesper because many times running java is not the sole purpose. many times you might have developed a program/application that is supposed to run specifically on 64 bit machines (or 32 bit machines) (the reason can be anything). in such places i'll need to check what version of of windows architecture is present ..

Comment: Related: [How do I detect which kind of JRE is installed — 32bit vs. 64bit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/807263/304)

Comment: @Jesper Another situation where discerning between 32 or 64 bit OS is of paramount importance is when a Java program must start an external executable, for which both versions exist. Like writing Selenium tests, where the right browser driver must be started. And the same need exists for discerning the operating system itself. I'm sure one can think of several more cases where something that is supposed to be "abstracted away" is not.

Comment: @Jesper You said it: _supposed_

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Please note, the `os.arch` property will only give you the architecture of the *JRE*, not of the underlying os.

If you install a 32 bit jre on a 64 bit system, `System.getProperty("os.arch")` will return `x86`

In order to actually determine the underlying architecture, you will need to write some native code.  See [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170305123805/https://mark.koli.ch/javas-osarch-system-property-is-the-bitness-of-the-jre-not-the-operating-system) for more info (and a link to sample native code)

Answer (score 78):

I don't exactly trust reading the os.arch system variable.   While it works if a user is running a 64bit JVM on a 64bit system.  It doesn't work if the user is running a 32bit JVM on a 64 bit system.

The following code works for properly detecting Windows 64-bit operating systems.   On a Windows 64 bit system the environment variable
"Programfiles(x86)" will be set.  It will NOT be set on a 32-bit system and java will read it as null.

```
boolean is64bit = false;
if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
    is64bit = (System.getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)") != null);
} else {
    is64bit = (System.getProperty("os.arch").indexOf("64") != -1);
}
```

For other operating systems like Linux or Solaris or Mac we may see this problem as well.  So this isn't a complete solution.  For mac you are probably safe because apple locks down the JVM to match the OS.  But Linux and Solaris, etc.. they may still use a 32-bit JVM on their 64-bit system.   So use this with caution.

Comment: "I don't exactly trust reading the `os.arch` system variable." The reason for this behaviour is that for e.g. [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) is important to know the arch of **[JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)**, not underlying OS (if you need to load into Java code your own platform dependent shared libraries, they need to be the same arch as JVM).

Comment: +1 After quite a bit of research I'm going to use this. But I'm curious, on this machine (Windows 8.1 64 bit) the environment variable `ProgramFiles(x86)` is not listed under "This PC" / Properties / Advanced System Settings / Environment Variables, yet `System.getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)")` does return the value `C:\Program Files (x86)`, which of course is great because it sounds like such variable cannot be modified or removed by users; is that the case ? Is `ProgramFiles(x86)` some kind of "internal" environment variable ?

Comment: this is still not reliable at all because one can erase environment variables before spawning the process. The better way is probably checking the existence of `%Windir%\SysWOW64` (meaning 64-bit process) and `%Windir%\Sysnative` (meaning 32-bit process running in 64-bit Windows)

Answer (score 5):

I used the command prompt (command --> wmic OS get OSArchitecture) to get the OS architecture. The following program helps get all the required parameters:

```
import java.io.*;

public class User {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("OS --> "+System.getProperty("os.name"));   //OS Name such as Windows/Linux

        System.out.println("JRE Architecture --> "+System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")+" bit.");       // JRE architecture i.e 64 bit or 32 bit JRE

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c","wmic OS get OSArchitecture");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        String result = getStringFromInputStream(p.getInputStream());

        if(result.contains("64"))
            System.out.println("OS Architecture --> is 64 bit");  //The OS Architecture
        else
            System.out.println("OS Architecture --> is 32 bit");

        }


    private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to share my Java code solution to this (the one alike is a native code).

I would like to add up to Mr James Van Huis's answer; since the property os.arch `System.getProperty("os.arch")` returns the bitness of JRE, this can actually be very useful. From the article:

> In your code, you first need to check the size of IntPtr, if it returns 8 then you are running on a 64-bit OS. If it returns 4, you are running a 32 bit application, so now you need to know whether you are running natively or under WOW64.

Therefore, the IntPtr size check is the same check you perform by looking at the "os.arch". After this you can proceed with figuring out whether the process is running natively or under WOW64.

This can be done using the jna library(e.g. [NativeLibrary](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html)) which offers use of the native functions you need.

```
//test the JRE here by checking the os.arch property
//go into the try block if JRE is 32bit
try {
    NativeLibrary kernel32Library = NativeLibrary.getInstance("kernel32");
    Function isWow64Function = kernel32Library.getFunction("IsWow64Process");

    WinNT.HANDLE hProcess = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetCurrentProcess();
    IntByReference isWow64 = new IntByReference(0);
    Boolean returnType = false;
    Object[] inArgs = {
        hProcess,
        isWow64
    };
    if ((Boolean) isWow64Function.invoke(returnType.getClass(), inArgs))    {
        if (isWow64.getValue() == 1)    {
                //32bit JRE on x64OS
        }
    }
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {  //thrown by getFunction

}
```

Something like this might also work, but I would recommend the first version, since it's the one I tested on x64 and 32bit JRE on x64 OS. Also it should be the safer way, because in the following you don't actually check whether or not the "IsWow64Process" function exists.

Here I am adding an example of the JRE check, just so it is complete, even though it's not hard to find.

```
Map<String, Integer> archMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
archMap.put("x86", 32);
archMap.put("i386", 32);
archMap.put("i486", 32);
archMap.put("i586", 32);
archMap.put("i686", 32);
archMap.put("x86_64", 64);
archMap.put("amd64", 64);
//archMap.put("powerpc", 3);
this.arch = archMap.get(SystemUtils.OS_ARCH);
if (this.arch == null)  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown architecture " + SystemUtils.OS_ARCH);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Only for Windows) Check if
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
exists.
if the directory exist, it is a 64 bit process.
Else, it is a 32 bit process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, I thinks it's better to detect the model of JVM

```
boolean is64bit = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").contains("64");
```

Comment: The OP asks about the OS not the JVM

Comment: Does nor work, checked on Windows 10 (64bit) with Java 8 32bit.

Comment: It could work or not; in some OS this key is absent. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807263/how-do-i-detect-which-kind-of-jre-is-installed-32bit-vs-64bit, the most voted answer. In my Win10 it is present.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it 's not the best way, but it works.

All I do is get the "Enviroment Variable" which windows has configured for Program Files x86 folder. I mean Windows x64 have the folder (Program Files x86) and the x86 does not. Because a user can change the Program Files path in `Enviroment Variables`, or he/she may make a directory "Program Files (x86)" in C:\, I will not use the detection of the folder but the "Enviroment Path" of "Program Files (x86)" with the variable in windows registry.

```
public class getSystemInfo {

    static void suckOsInfo(){

    // Get OS Name (Like: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows XP, etc.)
    String osVersion = System.getProperty("os.name");
    System.out.print(osVersion);

    String pFilesX86 = System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)");
    if (pFilesX86 !=(null)){
        // Put here the code to execute when Windows x64 are Detected
    System.out.println(" 64bit");
    }
    else{
        // Put here the code to execute when Windows x32 are Detected
    System.out.println(" 32bit");
    }

    System.out.println("Now getSystemInfo class will EXIT");
    System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: Well, user Boolean had already the same way but in a better code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "real" os arch from command line.
You can use "**wmic cpu get AddressWidth**".

[image]

If do you want the processor arch, you can use "**wmic cpu get DataWidth**"

I write a simple java static code to try this.

(**Disclaimer**: You need use ProcessBuilder if you want reuse this code)

```
public static String getOsArch() {
    String arch = null;
    try {
        arch = HotUtils.executeCmd("wmic cpu get AddressWidth");
        arch = arch.trim();
        arch = arch.replace("\n\n", "\n");
        arch = arch.replace(" ", "");
        arch = arch.trim();
        return arch.endsWith("64")? "64": "32";
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HotUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return arch;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(HotUtils.getOsArch());
}

public static String executeCmd(String cmd) throws IOException {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    String s;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(s);
    }

    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(s);
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: Why -1? Give me feedback, this is a hard but effective way to that.

Answer (score -3):

```
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

Comment: On 64b windows, but 32b jvm it prints "x86" for me. So I guess it doesn't say the version of system but rather virtual machine.

Answer (score -5):

You can use the os.arch property in system properties to find out.

```
Properties pr = System.getProperties();
System.out.println(pr.getProperty("os.arch"));
```

If you are on 32 bit, it should show i386 or something

Comment: on 64-bit OS running a 32-bit JVM, this will return x86, indicating 32-bit. While this is correct for the JVM, it is wrong for the OS, which is what the OP asked.