# How to find the OS bit type

Tags: java, architecture, properties, operating-system

I want to know the OS type, means is it of 64bit os or 32bit os. But I am getting different response from 32bit/64bit executable which getting system properties about OS

I am getting details from system property. and I have 64bit machine and OS windows 8.1 X64

```
        "OS Architecture : " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));

        "OS Name : " + System.getProperty("os.name"));

        "OS Version : " + System.getProperty("os.version")

        "Data Model : " + System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
```

---

### While running **64bit Executable** getting following response.

---

**OS Architecture** : **amd64**

**OS Name** : Windows 8

**OS Version** : 6.2 **amd64**

**Data Model** : 64

---

### While running **32bit Executable** getting following response.

---

**OS Architecture** : **x86**

**OS Name** : Windows 8

**OS Version** : 6.2 x86

**Data Model** : 32

---

**How can I get OS actual bit type ?**

Comment: data model if you see for same machine its returning both 32 and 64 according to the executable 32/64bits type

Comment: @TejKiran yes i got that so i have remove that comment and added solution.

Comment: @TGO: No, this question asks for a cross-platform solution, while the linked question is platform-specific.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution (which is also cross-platform IMO) is the answer given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2269242/1973164

> I don't exactly trust reading the os.arch system variable. While it works if a user is running a 64bit JVM on a 64bit system. It doesn't work if the user is running a 32bit JVM on a 64 bit system.
>
> The following code works for properly detecting Windows 64-bit operating systems. On a Windows 64 bit system the environment variable "Programfiles(x86)" will be set. It will NOT be set on a 32-bit system and java will read it as null.
>
> ```
> boolean is64bit = false;
> if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
>     is64bit = (System.getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)") != null);
> } else {
>     is64bit = (System.getProperty("os.arch").indexOf("64") != -1);
> }
> ```
>
> For other operating systems like Linux or Solaris or Mac we may see this problem as well. So this isn't a complete solution. For mac you are probably safe because apple locks down the JVM to match the OS. But Linux and Solaris, etc.. they may still use a 32-bit JVM on their 64-bit system. So use this with caution.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @KarlRichter Whilst the _answer_ you have linked to sounds reasonable, you are using a subjective _answer_ as a guidance to downvote other answers. I'm not linking to content outside of SO, rather, I'm linking to content already here. Meanwhile, I suggest you take a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), which specifically mentions to use comments in case you need clarification, and _edit_ the answer if you believe you have a _fix_; I believe you might have missed it.

Answer (score 2):

**System.getProperty("os.arch") will always return the bit type of the jre and not of the actual operating system.**

Write jni code  and calll `IsWow64Process` from winapi. Since you are using windows.

This boolean function tells you whether the process is running on 64-bit os.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

will return "x86" when the architecture of JRE is 32 bit. We have to write native code to get the real architecture of the system using JNI.

Comment: This property is giving unexpected result - while running 32bit executable giving x86 and for same code if run for 64bit executable then return amd64 even operating system is 64-bit

Comment: if the value contains x86, it should be a 32 bit os otherwise, it will be 64-bit. Am i right? Why is it downvoted?

Comment: os.arch returns the JVM characteristics - a 32 bit jvm running on a 64 bit os will return x86 for os.arch.

Comment: @assylias yes, i got it. I have updated my answer as well.