# Find out on which Java bit version my java application is running (Solution required in C# and Java)

Tags: java, c#

On my 64 bit PC I have installed both 32 bit and 64 bit JRE(Java Runtime Environment). I have a java application. According to my requirements I need to find out which of the installed java (32 bit or 64 bit), my application is using ?
Finding java version alone (example : 1.7, 1.8 etc.) is not enough. I need to find out which bit version of JRE (32 bit or 64 bit) my application is using ?

The same implementation I want to do in C# application. I mean I want to know from C# application that which bit version(32 or 64) any java application on same PC will use ?

Comment: Bit detection http://stackoverflow.com/q/1856565/1737819

Comment: There is almost always a way to avoid needing to know this. Why do you need this information as you may be able to run without it?

Comment: @Peter It is requirement of our project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SystemUtils` class from `org.apache.commons.lang` :

```
String bit = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"); //64
// commons-lang
String javaVersion = SystemUtils.JAVA_VERSION; //1.7.0_71
String jreVersion = SystemUtils.JAVA_RUNTIME_VERSION; //1.7.0_71-b14
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I want to extend my question. I want to know that the same solution can be implemented from C# application or not ? I mean I want to know from C# application that which bit version of Java a java application will use on same PC.