# Determining system architecture

Tags: java

How do I determine the architecture of the system I'm currently in (x86, x86_64, aarch64, etc)?
I **DO NOT** want the JVM architecture (which `System.getProperty("os.arch")` gives).
I've already looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856565/how-do-you-determine-32-or-64-bit-architecture-of-windows-using-java), but the answers are all for windows (obviously), and the top answer's link does not work anymore.

Comment: Updated the accepted answer link with an archived page link.

Comment: It does not answer my question, as the used class is no longer accessible in Java 18 without shenanigans (or it has even been removed entirely).

Comment: The other question you mentioned is asking how to determine whether one is running 32 or 64-bit Windows. I'm asking for an OS independent solution of determining the system architecture.

Comment: By the way if you don't find build in Java method you always can write shell script and execute it in Java. Look this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707519/running-a-bash-shell-script-in-java

Comment: There's probably no built-in function to give you what your looking for.  You would probably have to drop down to executing shell commands to get the info.  Here's a small demo I found doing a quick Google search: https://www.baeldung.com/run-shell-command-in-java

Comment: Another way is to make your own native c/c++ function to determinate, and run it using [JNI](https://www.baeldung.com/jni) like the accepted answer does

Comment: @ATP Note that accepted answer in the other question leads to native code example using `IsWow64Process` and Windows API docs for same say "Note that this technique is not a reliable way to detect whether the operating system is a 64-bit version of Windows"

Answer (score 2):

For non-Windows systems, you can use `uname -m`:

```
public static Optional<String> getSystemArchitecture()
throws IOException,
       InterruptedException {

    String name = null;

    ProcessBuilder builder;
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
        builder = new ProcessBuilder("wmic", "os", "get", "OSArchitecture");
    } else {
        builder = new ProcessBuilder("uname", "-m");
    }
    builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

    Process process = builder.start();

    try (BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            process.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset()))) {

        String line;
        while ((line = output.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                name = line;
            }
        }
    }

    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    if (exitCode != 0) {
        throw new IOException(
            "Process " + builder.command() + " returned " + exitCode);
    }

    return Optional.ofNullable(name);
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for an OS-independent solution that does not rely on the os.name system property.

Comment: @illuminator3 I see.  That definitely will be a challenge, since obtaining the architecture seems to be an OS-specific function.

Answer (score 1):

The `os.arch` system property is Java's offering in this area ([its description](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) is literally "Operating system architecture"), but you say you don't want that.  **Java has no other built-in mechanism for determining that information**.

Comment: Like I already said in my question, `os.arch` is the **JVM architecture**, not the **system architecture**.

Comment: And I already acknowledged that in this answer, @illuminator3.  And as this answer also says, Java doesn't offer anything else (built in).  I'm sorry that's not the answer you were hoping for.