# How to test from java code if the jvm supports -d64 option?

Tags: java, virtual-machine

I thought about using the following code, but is there any cleaner way?

```
Process theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -d64 -version");
BufferedReader errStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(theProcess.getErrorStream()));
System.out.println(errStream.readLine());
```

Comment: Why dó you need to know?

Comment: You should use `theProcess.waitFor() != 0` to decide whether it worked or not. Not *much* nicer though.

Comment: @Thorbjorn: I need to startup some other java code with or without -d64 option, depending upon whether the jvm supports it or not.

Comment: Feels like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to post this as an answer:

```
public static boolean supports64Bit() {
    try {
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -d64 -version");
        try {
            return process.waitFor() == 0;
        } finally {
            process.getInputStream().close();
            process.getOutputStream().close();
            process.getErrorStream().close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log error here?!
        return false;
    }
}
```

Closing all streams associated with a process is good practice and prevents resource leaks.

Not tested.

Comment: Another good idea is to do this only once and than cache the result in a static variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sun JVM, I think you can use the `sun.arch.data.model` system property (using the `System.getproperty()` to get this value.

Comment: What if jvm is from a different vendor?

Comment: I am not sure if the other JVMs have a property for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch")
if (arch.equals("amd64") || arch.equals("x86_64")) {
    // Machine is 64-bit
}
```

To determine whether the machine itself is a 64-bit machine. Not sure about checking the VM itself, though.

Comment: This is inaccurate and not to be trusted.

Comment: and what if `arch.matches("[Aa]lpha.*")` which is a a 64-bit machine? and if "x86_128" supports the -d64 option you'd say it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do so, may be through Java WebStart and a local JNLP file.  You then invoke "javaws foo.jnlp" with appropriate options.

You can have architecture dependent options and libraries.