# Java heap size: error when setting it too large

Tags: java, heap-memory

I have a program that fundamentally requires a lot of memory. However, for some reason java gives me an error when I try to set the max heap space above 1.5GB. That is, running

```
java -Xmx1582m [my program]
```

is okay, but

```
java -Xmx1583m [my program]
```

gives the error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I got the same error in both Windows command line and Eclipse.

Here are my system configurations:

Windows 7 (64-bit)

Intel Core 2 Quad CPU

Installed RAM: 8.00 GB

Java version 1.6.0

It is weird that I can only set 1.5GB memory even though I'm running 64-bit OS with 8 GB RAM. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Are you using a the JRE for Windows or Windows x64?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os

Comment: I know you said you have 8GB of RAM, but the text of the error matches the "you're using a bigger heap than there is memory available" error.  I think this may be a JVM limitation, but I'm still looking into it.

Comment: My java -version says:

java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode, sharing)

I can't tell whether this is 32- or 64-bit.

Comment: check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm) for the JVM info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The likely case is that while your *operating system* is 64-bit, your JVM is not. Opening a command line and typing `java -version` will give you the verbose version information, which should indicate whether your installed JVM is a 32 or 64-bit build.

A 64-bit JVM should have no problem with the higher memory limits.

Comment: Ah, it seems that installing the 64-bit JDK works! Problem solved! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Also, I hadn't realized that the 32-bit JVM doesn't mention it's 32-bit with `-version` (the 64-bit version actually says it's 64-bit), sorry about that!

Answer (score -3):

For heap space is used

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=64m
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Running
java -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xmx1583m [my program]
still gives the same error.

Comment: -1 `-XX:MaxPermSize` is for Permanent Generation. It's size is counted apart of the rest of the heap.