# InnoSetup: Detect if Java is 32-bit or 64-bit

Tags: java, jvm, inno-setup

In InnoSetup I run this code:

```
J32 := ShellExec('', 'java', '-d32 -version', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ec);
J64 := ShellExec('', 'java', '-d64 -version', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ec);
```

Both `J32` and `J64` are `True`.

In command line:

```
> java -d32 -version
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.

> echo %errorlevel%
1

> java -d64 -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)

> echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Why does `ShellExec()` ignore `Params`?

I tried `Exec()` also:

```
// this way
J32 := Exec('java', '-d32 -version', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ec);
// and this way
J32 := Exec('>', 'java -d32 -version', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ec);
```

They all return `True`, and `ec = 1`, despite the fact that I have a 64-bit java.

It seems that `Exec` and `ShellExec` return `True` because they *succeed to run* `java`, but they do not track the error code `java` returns.

Comment: ShellExec never waits for the process to complete. However, your second to last command (`Exec('java', '-d32 -version' ...`) looks fine. What was in `ec` after it ran? What was in `J32`?

Comment: Pascal Scripting: ShellExec documentation says that: "The Wait parameter specifies whether the function should return immediately or wait until the launched process has termimated or is idle."

Comment: `ec = 1`. It is always 1 when the call is successful.
`J32 = True`

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm

Comment: @Gray: thanks, I know about this question. It asks, however, about detecting the JVM version from within the Java program.

Answer (score 1):

The Inno Setup help states:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesinstallin64bitmode

> The System32 path returned by the {sys} constant maps to the 64-bit
>   System directory by default when used in the [Dirs], [Files],
>   [InstallDelete], [Run], [UninstallDelete], and [UninstallRun]
>   sections. This is because Setup/Uninstall temporarily disables WOW64
>   file system redirection [external link] when files/directories are
>   accessed by those sections. Elsewhere, System32 and {sys} map to the
>   32-bit System directory, as is normal in a 32-bit process.

So in 64-bit mode in the [Code] section, everything is 32-bit.  It will execute 32-bit Java and c:\Windows\System32 points to the WOW64 folder, i.e. the 32-bit version of System32.

This answer shows how to check Java in the registry instead:

[Need help on Inno Setup script - issue in check the jre install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783959/need-help-on-inno-setup-script-issue-in-check-the-jre-install)

Following that answer, the following code seems to work to check whether 64-bit Java 1.7+ is installed:

```
[Code]

function JavaIsMissing(): Boolean;
var 
javaVersionOutput: AnsiString;

begin

result := not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64, 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment',
   'CurrentVersion', javaVersionOutput);
if not result then
   result := CompareStr(javaVersionOutput, '1.7') < 0;
end;

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\{#JavaInstaller}"; StatusMsg: "Java Runtime Enviroment not installed on your system. Installing..."; Check: JavaIsMissing
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something I could use across multiple Inno Setup projects, so I wrote a DLL for detecting Java details (home directory, etc.):

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/JavaInfo

Download from here: https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/JavaInfo/releases

The download includes a sample Inno Setup `.iss` script that demonstrates how to use the DLL functions (including how to check whether 32-bit or 64-bit).