# RWeka won't load

Tags: java, r, rweka

Can't get the RWeka package to be added to the library.  I can install.packages("RWeka") but when I load library(RWeka), I get an error message, "No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures."  I have re-installed Java but I do not know what matching architectures means. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: are you using 32bit or 64bit R? use `R.Version()` if you are not sure.

Comment: Yes, I am using 64 bit R newest version 3.1.3 in Windows 10.  R.Version shows the architechture as "x86_64".  have updated to a new version of Java also.

Comment: Sorry, correction on the version of R.  I have R version 3.3.2.  It is the 64 bit version.

Comment: U will need to have 64 bit java installed as well. There should be a folder in 'c:\program files\java' not just in 'c:\program files (x86)\java'

Comment: Well I am looking around trying to document that I have Java 64 bit.  Can't  find where it says 64 bit.  I have version Java 8 build 1.8.0.  I have to admit to a lifelong abhorrence of Java.  I avoid Java anytime I can.I do have folder c:\program files\java and c:\program files (x86\java.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825244/how-do-i-detect-whether-32-bit-java-is-installed-on-x64-windows-only-looking-at. it shows how to check the version installed. you will need to run the same architecture for R and Java.