# Java JVM limits for --Xmx

Tags: java, windows, memory, jvm

I am running a java app on a Windows 10 machine via

```
JAVA -Xms1500M -Xmx1600M -jar appname.jar
```

The app fails after a while with an error stating not enough heap space. When it is running using Task Manager I can see I am using about 50% of the total memory available on the machine.

If I try and increase the -Xmx space then I get an error saying it cannot be allocated - why is this as there is plenty of memory free?

The Java app is a 3rd party and I know it runs on colleagues pcs

[image]

My JVM version is

[image]

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  Are you running a 32 bit JVM?  What does `java -version` print out.

Comment: I am on a 64bit machine with 12Gb memory

Comment: Java version info has been added to the question

Comment: With 32 bit you'd have a 4GB limit

Comment: @gurioso - In practice, on Windows it is about 1.6GB.  See the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are running a 32 bit JVM.  (According to the version info you have an Oracle release, and Java 8 was the last versin that Oracle provided 32 bit downloadables for.)

Assuming that is the case, the max heap size for a 32 bit Java on Windows is limited to between 1.4 and 1.6GB.  The limit is a result of the way that Windows allocates virtual address spaces.  For more details read:

- [Frequently Asked Questions About the Java HotSpot VM: "Why can't I get a larger heap with the 32-bit JVM?"](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit)

The solution is to download and install a 64 bit Java release for Windows.  You want a download for the "x86-64" architecture.

(I notice that you are running 1.8.0_101.  That was released in July 2016 and is way out of date.  At time of writing, the most recent Java 8 release is 1.8.0_231.)

---

> The Java app is a 3rd party and I know it runs on colleagues pcs

They probably have installed 64 bit Java.

Comment: Thanks - that was the issue I was running a 32 bit version. Removed it and added 64 bit version. It works fine now.

Comment: I used this to find the version I was running https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825244/how-do-i-detect-whether-32-bit-java-is-installed-on-x64-windows-only-looking-at