# JRE or JDK must be... Java - Eclipse issue

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, eclipse

Downloaded and extracted Eclipse 64-bit yesterday.
I've spent hours and hours trying to make eclipse and java work together, but it seems impossible.

You can see a picture of the error here:

[image]

I've tried: searching online, modded my eclipse.ini, tried downloading ecplise 32-bit, made a shortcut to my eclipse.exe and modded the shortcut, reinstalling Java, downloaded eclipse again, ran the programs (java and eclipse) in compability mode (admin & non-admin).

I've tried everything i can think of!

Please help.

Everytime i find a solution, a new error appears.

Some of the errors i've gotten:
NUMBER 1: http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_9EcOiQEHa3eadI57HBy3LDUwLvGKKpbnEhrbRJifhpMmXUwUVw

NUMBER 2: http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS2fg_fRx7fpyrhjcMtkz9o5K6i6jfrsUATJZyNOlxlrqLBScyM

NUMBER 3: http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPquudPnCHeKQRj8tQvF6FwgHwNDzyJkKQMBl3qVdqe6TG2oB6

And so on...

Please help me :/

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the environment Variable "PATH" to the proper location of the java binaries. Since your screenshot exposes you are using windows try google "setting an environment variable  in windows".

Comment: Your tip worked (kind off).
Now i get this error; http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXL4AX3NkkgnVcTyWUmG_0jb7Rvyfqt_6nrvnNlDrbfQBvjUAFjg

Help me :/

Comment: Maybe you downloaded the wrong Version of Java or Eclipse. Figure out if your System is 32/64 bit and download the right Version of the software. Probably you got Eclipse 64 Bit and Java 32 Bit or Vice-Versa..

Comment: Additionally I want to forward you to following discussion - It should give you the answers: [Problems with 64/32 Bit](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/170758/)

Comment: confusing... So if i download 32 bit eclipse now, it will work?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html

Downloaded this. (A guy told me it would help.) Didn't do anything.

So I'm still at this error: http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXL4AX3NkkgnVcTyWUmG_0jb7Rvyfqt_6nrvnNlDrbfQBvjUAFjg

Help me please :)

Comment: IT WORKS!  THANKS EVERYODY! ILY GUYS!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to do things methodologically:

- Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and download the latest JDK (Java Development Kit). Do not download the JRE. Install the JDK.
- Go to http://eclipse.org/downloads/ and download the latest Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. Install it.

Everything should be fine.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html

Downloaded this. (A guy told me it would help.) Didn't do anything.

So I'm still at this error: http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXL4AX3NkkgnVcTyWUmG_0jb7Rvyfqt_6nrvnNlDrbfQBvjUAFjg

Help me please :)

Comment: IT WORKS!  THANKS EVERYODY! ILY GUYS!

Answer (score 0):

Start Eclipse using the -vm command line option. For example,

```
-vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw"
```

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work.
I got this error now: http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXL4AX3NkkgnVcTyWUmG_0jb7Rvyfqt_6nrvnNlDrbfQBvjUAFjg

Comment: Are you trying to run 64-bit Eclipse using the 32-bit JVM? That won't work.

Comment: I don't know what my JVM version is. How do i check?

Comment: It says:
Java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (Build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java hotspot(TM) Client VM (Build 20.5-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

Can't see how that info helps you/us, but.

Comment: @user1202166 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm

Comment: Given that your new error indicates the JRE is installed under the Program Files(x86) directory, that would be 32-bit. So, if you were trying with 64-bit Eclipse, that is a problem. You would need the 64-bit JDK or 32-bit Eclipse.

Comment: IT WORKS!  THANKS EVERYODY! ILY GUYS!