# How Can I check 32bit or 64bit in custom code or API

Tags: install4j

How Can I check 32bit or 64bit in Install4j API (custom code)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check whether the installer is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows, use

```
Util.is64BitWindows()
```

in the install4j API. This works regardless of whether it's called in a 32-bit or a 64-bit installer. To check whether the current JVM is a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm)

Comment: thank you. Util.is64BitWindows() can check jsut 32-bit JVM or 64-bit JVM. It depends on JVM. I want to check real OS Architecture.  Though my OS Architecture is 64bit machane, it shows 32-bit on 32-bit JVM.

Comment: @HeesukKim No, `Util.is64BitWindows()` checks the OS architecture, not the JVM. Do you really get `false` on a 64-bit Windows?