# How to check What architecture JDK was build for? / Whether installed JDK on mac is for arm (aka arm64) or for Intel CPU (aka amd64)?

Tags: java, macos, arm, x86-64, apple-m1

Because on Apple with M1, M2 ... (Apple Silicon) it is possible to install both JDK for arm (aka arm64) or for Intel CPU (aka amd64), and it will just work, there is problem to tell (to colleague on other mac) how to check

**How to check that installed JDK on mac is for arm64 or amd64 ?**

1. From command line?
2. From within Java program? (not the OS arch `System.getProperty("os.arch")`)

For example `mvn -v` used to be enough to tell all details.

```bash
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.1 (2e178502fcdbffc201671fb2537d0cb4b4cc58f8)
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/libexec
Java version: 17.0.6, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: /Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.6-1/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.4", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

JDK java/javac don't give clue either.

```bash
javac -version
javac 17.0.6

java -version
openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.6.10.1 (build 17.0.6+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.6.10.1 (build 17.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

We also have JDK installed by scripts, JDK installed in docker container.
There should be some common way to check.

Comment: On linux I would do `file $(which javac)` and it would tell me what kind of architecture it was compiled for. Not sure it works on mac but worth a try.

Comment: When Java was developed I don't think anybody considered that an os may be able to execute more than one architecture.  And the common way to check if an app uses Rosetta isn't feasible in Java: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653009. The only way I see is by try and error e.g. by trying to load a library of MacOS you know that is arm64 via `System.load()`. If this works Java is an arm64 version.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Great, that works on macOS, and could become accepted answer.

Comment: @PaulVerest and an answer it is, now.

Comment: @Robert At least it is possibly from command line 'file $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac'
So so it would be possible (thought no nice) to run similar from within Java

Comment: Considering the answer from Federico you could search for a library that allows to parse MachO files and that can handle thin and fat binaries and allows to extract the info what architectures the contained Macho files require. Then you could read the Java binary that is currently executed to get the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need to check by hand you can use the `file` utility which, for executables, should tell you what architecture the binary was built for.

So assuming you want to know about the `javac` that's on your path you can run

```
file $(which javac)
```

Or, more generally

```
file /path/to/your/binary
```

And read its output.

An example:

`$ file $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac`

> /Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/bin/javac: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

`$ file $JAVA_OTHER_HOME/bin/javac`

> /Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362-1/Contents/Home/bin/javac: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes knowing/using the correct words is already half way. Now I could find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105253/determine-jre-architecture-32-bit-vs-64-bit and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm-from-within-a-program that used to be common problem.

Answer (score 3):

on macOS 14 and later the easiest way is to use the command:

`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

the answer will be something like this

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    21.0.1 (arm64) "Eclipse Adoptium" - "OpenJDK 21.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-21.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-21.jdk/Contents/Home
```

so:
`21.0.1` -> version
`arm64` -> architecture (Apple Sillicon)
`Eclipse Adoptium` -> distribution