# Windows bat file determining if Java install is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: java, batch-file, 32bit-64bit

Is it possible using a Windows batch file to determine if the version of Java (assuming 7) installed is the 32 bit version or the 64 bit version?

Comment: Is it just that it is installed, or in the path as well.  I have many versions installed to support different projects

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2062263/1393766

Comment: @RobGoodwin assuming it is installed - it is which version it is.

Comment: From what I've seen, most look for the existance of environment variables like JAVA_HOME

Comment: @MadProgrammer so you're saying parse the JAVA_HOME based on whether it is in the 32 bit Program Files directory or not...

Comment: @hawkeye That would one approach, but that will only tell you where `JAVA_HOME` points.  You could also look at `ProgramFiles(x86)` and `ProgramFiles` to see if "Java\" exists

Comment: @hawkeye You can have more than one.  Are you interested in figuring this information out for all installations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a small windows script to get you started that will determine Java32 vs Java64 vs JavaNotInstalled.

Tweak as necessary...

```
@echo off
java -d64 -version >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 goto maybe32bit
echo Java is 64 bit 
goto EXIT
:maybe32bit
where java >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 goto nojava
echo Java is 32 bit 
goto EXIT
:nojava
echo Java is not installed
:EXIT
```

Comment: @WestFarmer - Be more specific and perhaps open a question with the specific symptoms. Then, add a pointer here to the question.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. Works with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The bat file could run `java -version` and parse the output.