# Method to tell if I am running inside a 32 or 64 Bit JVM

Tags: java

This is a common enough question and always seems to throw up the usual arguments between using sun.arch.data.model"  OR "os.arch" as a way of telling.

for example this post .... [How can I tell if I'm running in 64-bit JVM or 32-bit JVM (from within a program)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm-from-within-a-program)

I have put this quick method together,  can anyone spot any loop holes as I want to cover all possibilities as our app may be deployed on AWS servers or standalone machines

```
private static boolean is64BitJVM()
{
    String jvmBitSizeUsingSunProperty = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
    if( jvmBitSizeUsingSunProperty != null && jvmBitSizeUsingSunProperty.length() > 0)
    {
        return jvmBitSizeUsingSunProperty.contains("64");
    }
    else
    {
        String jvmBitSizeUsing_os_Property = System.getProperty("os.arch");
        if( jvmBitSizeUsing_os_Property != null && jvmBitSizeUsing_os_Property.length() > 0)
        {
            return jvmBitSizeUsing_os_Property.contains("64");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
if (test)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

you can just do

```
return test;
```

Comment: It can't be said often enough ... +1