# How to check that a jre environment is 32 bit or 64 bit programmatically with C#?

Tags: c#, java, jvm-hotspot, jvm-crash

I have a jre folder which is basically java runtime, it is not installed I have copied this folder from somewhere else, now I need to check this jre is 32 bit or 64 bit with manual inspection without writing any code and if code has to be written then it should be c#.
All the example tell system.getproperty("java...model") something for getting the target type of the installed jre, but I dont have this jre installed, rather I have just copied this jre. 
so is there any way to know its target type is it 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: even if it is not installed, the java executable in the bin folder should react to a `java -version`...

Comment: Check the version (32 vs 64) on the system you've copied it from.

Answer (score 1):

**C# Code**

```
// *** Main code
string output = RunExternalExe("java.exe -version");

// Parse output here...


// *** Helper methods
public string RunExternalExe(string filename, string arguments = null)
{
    var process = new Process();

    process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arguments))
    {
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    }

    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    var stdOutput = new StringBuilder();
    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => stdOutput.Append(args.Data);

    string stdError = null;
    try
    {
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        stdError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("OS error while executing " + Format(filename, arguments)+ ": " + e.Message, e);
    }

    if (process.ExitCode == 0)
    {
        return stdOutput.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        var message = new StringBuilder();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdError))
        {
            message.AppendLine(stdError);
        }

        if (stdOutput.Length != 0)
        {
            message.AppendLine("Std output:");
            message.AppendLine(stdOutput.ToString());
        }

        throw new Exception(Format(filename, arguments) + " finished with exit code = " + process.ExitCode + ": " + message);
    }
}

private string Format(string filename, string arguments)
{
    return "'" + filename + 
        ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(arguments)) ? string.Empty : " " + arguments) +
        "'";
}
```

**COMMAND sample output**
On my box I have a 64bit java version. Here is its output:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin>java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Note the *64-Bit* mention. You may find this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2062263/363573) useful.

Comment: So if I type java.exe -version in CMD, I can see the output. But if I run the code you wrote, I got an exception saying java.exe is not found. Is there a difference running CMD directly and Process.Start?

Comment: @Hoky22 Check java is installed on your box. If so check it is accessible in the PATH environement variable. Last check, edit the code and add the absolute path to java.exe.

Comment: Java is installed and is set in the Path environment variable. I am trying not to hard code the absolute path though, for my case, it's in C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath I suspect you can install it in other places

Answer (score 0):

You could use the GNU `file` utility to check whether or not java.exe is a 64-bit-executable.

See [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/103071/quick-way-to-tell-if-an-installed-application-is-64-bit-or-32-bit) for more information about that.

This way, you can avoid starting the unknown java.exe from your code, but instead your program has to start the `file` utility you have provided yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to this, but I wrote these methods in C# so that it can detect both 32/64-bit JRE and JDK because the provided answers don't suffice my need

```
private string CheckJreJdkVersion()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    string jre = @"SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment";
    string jdk = @"SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit";
    string jreInstallDirValueName = "INSTALLDIR";
    string jdkInstallDirValueName = "JavaHome";
    // Check 32-bit JRE
    GetJreJdkVersion(jre, RegistryView.Registry32, jreInstallDirValueName, ref sb, "JRE", "32");
    // Check 64-bit JRE
    GetJreJdkVersion(jre, RegistryView.Registry64, jreInstallDirValueName, ref sb, "JRE", "64");
    // Check 32-bit JDK
    GetJreJdkVersion(jdk, RegistryView.Registry32, jdkInstallDirValueName, ref sb, "JDK", "32");
    // Check 64-bit JDK
    GetJreJdkVersion(jdk, RegistryView.Registry64, jdkInstallDirValueName, ref sb, "JDK", "64");

    string res = sb.ToString();
    return res;
}

private void GetJreJdkVersion(string jreJdkPath, RegistryView registryView, string jreJdkInstallDirValueName, ref StringBuilder sb, string jreJdk, string bitVer)
{
    RegistryKey key = GetRegistryKeyHKLM(jreJdkPath, registryView);
    if (key == null)
        return;

    List<string> lstVersions = new List<string>();
    foreach (var version in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        lstVersions.Add(version);
    }

    IEnumerable<string> relevantVersions = GetRelevantVersions(lstVersions);

    foreach (var relevantVersion in relevantVersions)
    {
        string regPath = string.Empty;
        if (jreJdk == "JRE")
        {
            regPath = Path.Combine(jreJdkPath, Path.Combine(relevantVersion, "MSI"));
        }
        else
        {
            regPath = Path.Combine(jreJdkPath, relevantVersion);
        }

        string installDir = GetRegistryValueHKLM(regPath, jreJdkInstallDirValueName, registryView);

        sb.Append("Detected " + bitVer + "-bit " + jreJdk + ", install directory: " + installDir + "\n");
    }
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetRelevantVersions(List<string> lstVersions)
{
    IEnumerable<string> versions = lstVersions.Where(version => version.Contains("_"));

    return versions;
}

public RegistryKey GetRegistryKeyHKLM(string keyPath, RegistryView view)
{
    RegistryKey localMachineRegistry
        = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, view);

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyPath)
        ? localMachineRegistry
        : localMachineRegistry.OpenSubKey(keyPath);
}

public string GetRegistryValueHKLM(string keyPath, string keyName, RegistryView view)
{
    RegistryKey registry = GetRegistryKeyHKLM(keyPath, view);
    if (registry == null) return null;

    string value = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        value = registry.GetValue(keyName).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    return value;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Detected 32-bit JRE, install directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\
Detected 32-bit JRE, install directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\
Detected 32-bit JRE, install directory: C:\New folder\
Detected 64-bit JRE, install directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\
Detected 32-bit JDK, install directory: C:\jdk fol
```