# How to detect the JRE bit(32 or 64-bit) from VC++ code

Tags: java, visual-c++

I want to detect the Java Runtime Environment bit(32 or 64) programmatically using VC++.Please suggest how can I do this.

Comment: Are you a win user or unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its fairly simple actualy, you can use system("command") to see its version(dont forget to include stdlib.h) like this:

```
system("java -d64 -version");
```

and on your console you will get the reaply, if it says :

> This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM. Please install the desired version

this means it's not a 64-bit version.

you can read much more about it in here:
[detect jre bit version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm-from-within-a-program)