# Problems requiring rJava in Windows

Tags: r, windows, rjava

I am using a 64-bit machine, with the latest version of R (3.1.2), the latest RStudio version (0.98.1091) and the latest JAVA (Version 8 Update 31).

I tried to require rJava (rJava_0.9-6) and the result is the following error:

```
require(xlsx)
Carregando pacotes exigidos: rJava
Error : .onLoad falhou em loadNamespace() para 'rJava', detalhes: 
chamada: fun(libname, pkgname)
erro: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Failed with error:  ‘package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded’
```

I already tried to re-install Java with no sucess.

Does anybody know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is your Java also 64-bit? I think you might have a 32-bit Java and that's what the 'R and Java have different architectures' error means.

Comment: I have done the standard installation procedure in java.com. How can I verify if it installed the 32-bit instead of the 64-bit?

Comment: `java -d64 -version` on command line. Taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm-from-within-a-program)

Comment: @LyzandeR you were correct! I do not know why JAVA standart setup was installing 32bit configuration. I did it manually and everything is going well. Would you like to do an answer? I think the question will help other users. Or I will just delete the question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I will provide an answer just in case it helps :). thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the problem on this occasion is that your Java is 32-bit, whereas your R is 64-bit. This is why you get a `R and Java have different architectures` error.

In order to check what your Java version is on Windows type:

```
java -d64 -version
```

on the command line as it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm-from-within-a-program).

I think that once you install the correct Java version i.e. the 64-bit on this occasion then loading your `xlsx` library will work!

Comment: You may also check your Java version from within R by typing `system("java -version")`

Answer (score 4):

The architecture of Java you get for install [from the regular Java download web page](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) depends on the architecture of browser you’re using (32-bit or 64-bit) when you download it.  This happens without any fanfare.   Try the [Java manual download page](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp), select the 64-bit version of Java for your OS, install it, and then (after restarting R) try your R packages again.