# Package xlxs installation in R has issues

Tags: java, r, r-xlsx

When trying to install package xlxs in R I get the following error.

error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.

Not sure what to do.  I have tried reinstalling Java and still get the same error.

I have R 3.12 on a windows 10 computer.

Any advice is welcome,

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but your R version is almost 3 years old. The latest is 3.4.2. The issue here is that the Java version needs to match your system architecture (32 or 64-bit). Google the error and you'll find several StackOverflow posts on this topic. Another option is to use `readxl` instead and avoid Java hell altogether.

Comment: Also , this might be in play :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367964/problems-requiring-rjava-in-windows

Comment: Also, you need to configure R for java, at the command prompt `R CMD javareconf`

Comment: I can use readxl to read excel file. How do I write in to excel file?

Comment: `readxl` doesn't write to Excel. There's a `writexl` package: https://github.com/ropensci/writexl. Or the `openxlsx` package: https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx. Or you could write to CSV and import.

Comment: neilfws and R.S,  Installing Java 64 seems to solve this issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! 
Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching
architectures.
```

The error normally occurs when the architectures(32/64 bit) of java and r does not match.

In order to check the version of java, type `java -version` in cmd.

You can follow below given steps:

**Rstudio > tools > global options  > general settings > R-version > change (to the architecture same as that of java) > apply**

[image: Screenshot of how it may look]
And you're good to go.