# Java ODBC Ms Access Driver

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, driver, jdbc-odbc

I am using the following specifications,
[image]

and I want to learn about Java to Microsoft Access, you can visit the update [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768591/eclipse-unknown-source-java-sql-exception?noredirect=1#comment55352481_33768591)

However, there's 2 Files `odbcad32` on my system, the first one located on `system32`
[image]

and the second one located on `syswow64`
[image]

I don't know if my Java application is using ODBC on `System32` or `syswow64`,

When i used the following code

```
public static String DBase =  "jdbc:odbc:datasource_access";
```

the error shows :

> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

but when i used the following code

```
public static String DBase =  "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb)};DBQ=D:\\Java\\u_1401087265\\1401087265db.mdb;";
```

the error shows

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified

It looks like that my Java application is using `odbcad32` on `System 32` but as we can see, there's no such a `Microsoft Access driver 32 bit` installed on system, although i have download and install [this software](https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Is there any way to change my Java application to run using `odbcad32` on `Syswow64` folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know if my Java application is using ODBC on System32 or syswow64

Have your application display the value returned by

```java
System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")
```

It will return either "32" or "64" indicating that the application is running in a 32-bit or 64-bit Java Virtual Machine (JVM). You need to be running under a 32-bit JVM to use the DSNs created by "SYSWOW64\odbcad32.exe".

> Is there any way to change my Java application to run using odbcad32 on Syswow64 folder ?

Install a 32-bit JVM and run your application with it.

Comment: do you mean that my system is already installed `Java` 64bit inside ? so i have to replace them to 32bit ?

Comment: It does sound likely that your machine has a 64-bit version of Java installed. Even so, it is possible to have more than one JVM installed on a machine so you don't necessarily have to *replace* your current Java components, just install a 32-bit JVM and configure your project to use it.

Comment: i tried `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")` and it returns `64` , does it mean that my java application is 64bit apps, or Java VM on my computer is 64bit ?

however, assuming that i continue to develop my 64bit apps with 64 bit JVM and jdbc odbc driver existed above, is that still possible ?

Comment: It means that your Java application is currently running in a 64-bit Java Virtual Machine (JVM). It does not imply that there is anything about your code that *requires* it to run in a 64-bit environment. So, you should be able to install a 32-bit JVM and use that to run your app.

Comment: ... or, you could use the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver and avoid this ODBC nonsense altogether. Details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).