# Failed to find the re quired library mclmcrrt9_3.dll on java.library.path

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I intend to convert my MATLAB code into java. I am following [this](https://se.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-java-application-with-matlab-code.html) official documentation. But after compiling using `javac` I am unable to run the final step. 
When I run this from cmd `java -classpath .;"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v93\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar";makesqr.jar getmagic 5`

I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to find the re
quired library mclmcrrt9_3.dll on java.library.path.
This library is typically installed along with MATLAB or the MATLAB Runtime. Its
 absence may indicate an issue with that installation or
the current path configuration, or a mismatch with the architecture of the Java
interpreter on the path.
MATLAB Runtime version this component is attempting to use: 9.3.
Java interpreter architecture: win32.
```

In my opinion this is a **[MATLAB Runtime](https://se.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/dotnet/install-the-matlab-runtime.html)** error not a java error and I am not able to fix it.

My setup is as follows

- Matlab Command Line

  > > version -java
  > >         'Java 1.8.0_121-b13 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode'
  > >
  > > computer('arch')
  > >         'win64'
- cmd

  > > java full version "1.8.0_152-b16"

I have installed the MATLAB Runtime using the online installer and `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v93\runtime\win64` is added to my PATH variable. So I am not sure what else do I need to do in order for step 17 to work. One thing I noticed is that the error message shows

```
Java interpreter architecture: win32.
```

I don't know why the architecture is shown as win32 even though all the software I have installed is for 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days I got back to this and found the problem. Thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm-from-within-a-program) I rechecked the java installed on my machine. Turns out it was 32 bit and not 64 bit. After installing the correct version the problem was solved.