# JMeter Dashboard Generation Java Heap Space

Tags: java, jmeter, dashboard

I've been able to create dashboards for small amounts of log data (3mb) with JMeter. However, when trying to create dashboards with large amounts of data (35mb), jmeter will throw a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space.

So far I've tried to create an environment variable called JVM_ARGS=-Xms1024m -Xmx10240m but I still do not have enough space.

Is there anything else I can try to create these dashboards? Or is there a way to reduce the number of entries that get written to the log file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities :

- Option 1 : your JVM options are not taken into account. Show the first lines or all content of  jmeter.log
- Option 2 : you have added some dynamic parameter to your http requests that has created a lot of different (name) SampleResult

**Edit 8 october 2018:**

- Root cause was point Option 2

Comment: I don't have my work computer on me at the moment but you are right, there is some dynamic parameter in my http request. I'll try to remove those from being added to my log. If that doesn't work, I'll post the contents of my jmeter log. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to remove the dynamic parameter and I can now successfully create dashboards for a larger set of data. However, I still want to include the dynamic data in my dashboards. Is there a way to have the request that creates a dynamic url all fall under the same SampleResult?

Comment: I would suggest that you accept this answer , and  ask another question with this clear context. I'll try to answer. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704881/consolidate-jmeter-sampleresult-entries

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you've **really** created the environment variable and it has the anticipated value, double check this by running the following command in the terminal window where you will be launching JMeter from:

   - `echo %JVM_ARGS%` for Windows
   - `echo $JVM_ARGS` for Linux/Unix/MacOS

     You should see your increased JVM heap settings

     [image: JMeter Increase Heap]
2. Make sure to use either `jmeter.bat` for Windows or `jmeter.sh` for other operating systems wrapper script
3. Make sure to use [64-bit version of JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm-from-within-a-program) as 32-bit will not be able to allocate more than 3G heap
4. Make sure you can execute `java` command with your 10G heap

   ```
   java -Xms1024m -Xmx10240m -version
   ```

   you should see your Java version

   [image: Java version]
5. Try running `ApacheJMeter.jar` executable directly:

   ```
   java -Xms1024m -Xmx10240m -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -g result.jtl -o destination_folder
   ```
6. If nothing helps be aware that you can generate tables/charts using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) (it is not a part of standard JMeter installation, can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager))

   [image: JMeter Plugins Command Line Graph Plotting Tool]

Comment: Thank you for your in depth answer. Unfortunately, it still throws a OutOfMemoryError. I believe it's because every http request I'm making, it makes a unique entry because a portion of the URL is dynamic. Is there a way to have them consolidate under the same entry?

For example:
example.com/<unique-id>
example.com/<another-unique-id>

This creates 2 distinct entries in my dashboards but I want them to be under the same entry.

Comment: 1. Put your request(s) under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)  2. Tick `Generate Parent Sample` box 3. Add `jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false` line to *user.properties* file