# Consolidate JMeter SampleResult Entries

Tags: jmeter

I'm making an HTTP Request where a component of the path is dynamic, resulting in unique Sample Results.

For example:
example.com/UNIQUE_ID

The UNIQUE_ID will change upon every request and create a unique request label like in the picture below:

[image]

Is there a way to consolidate them under a single entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with following code:

```
String oldLabel = prev.getSampleLabel();
if(oldLabel.startsWith("example.com/")) {
     prev.setSampleLabel("MyUniqueSample");
}
```

And [scope](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) it this way:

[image: JSR223 Scoped as child of Thread Group]

Answer (score 0):

Just put your request(s) under a [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) and tick `Generate parent sample` box - dynamic names will be stored by the Transaction Controller's name.

---

If you're using JMeter 5.0 you will also need to add the next line to [*user.properties* file:](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
```