# pyspark :Java heap space error throwen after changing StringIndexer params "handleInvalid" to 'skip'

Tags: pyspark, heap-memory

I'm working on a machine learning application ( using pycharm ) and everything works perfectly fine.

But spark throws this java heap error when i decided to change the 'HandlInvalid' param.

```
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
.....
.....
ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread driver-heartbeater
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
.....
.....
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o6473.fit.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

And when i try to change th driver.memory i get this error:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx5g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
```

here's my spark session :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Ope inp').master('local')\
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "5g")\
    .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

quoted from apache.spark.config :

> Note: In client mode, this config must not be set through the
>   SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has
>   already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the
>   --driver-memory command line option or in your default properties file

how can I set the *driver.memroy* and *executor.memory* config in files properties so i dont have to set them everytime i'm dubugging the application

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

The problem were solved thanks to 64 bit JVM.First I was running a 32 JVM which doesnt allow specific params of limit heap size.

to figure out which JVM you have . try the second answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/2062263/7096004][1]