# Launch4J - bundling a JRE for Windows 7 64-bit machines

Tags: bundle, java, freeze, launch4j

I've used Launch4J (along with Inno Setup Compiler) to create a desktop app.

It works fine on Windows 7 32-bit, but on Windows 7 64-bit the JRE hangs. Presumably, this is because I bundled in a 32-but JRE (jre6).

I'm wondering if anyone knows if it's possible (or even necessary) to bundle in one or more JREs so that my same app will work on 64-but systems?

Have read this page - http://java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml - and there doesn't seem to be many clues. I was bundling jre6 though, so maybe jre7 has fixed this issue?

Do not have a 64-bit setup to test on, so would be great if anyone with any experience here could share their knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to develop and test exclusively in a 32 bit environment I would highly recommend you force your application to run in a 32 bit JRE even on 64 bit machines.

Information on how to configure Launch4J to force 32 bit JRE here: [Configure Launch4J to use 32-bit JVM only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688932/configure-launch4j-to-use-32-bit-jvm-only)