# Require a 32-bit JRE when run an EXE

Tags: java, exe, 32bit-64bit, launch4j

I build an EXE from my Maven project with Launch4j, which is written with `jdk1.8.0_172 64-bit`. 
But when I tried to launch the EXE file from CMD or Git bash, it says

> This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0 (32-bit)

Do you have any idea why it happens and what I should do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit JRE installed?

Comment: @SLaks did you read the question? OP wants this to run with 64 bit JRE, so he does not have 32 bit one.

Comment: Try checking similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688932/configure-launch4j-to-use-32-bit-jvm-only. you might be able to check the configurations pointed in the answer

Comment: @PriyaJain Yes thanks for the advice. Effectively I put 32 bit by error in pom the value of <runtimeBits> instead of 64. Very stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the value of this property in pom:

```
 <plugin>
      <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <configuration>
                   <jre>
                       <bundledJre64Bit>true</bundledJre64Bit>
                       <runtimeBits>64</runtimeBits>
                   </jre>
              </configuration>
          </execution>
      </executions>
 </plugin>
```