# how can I check whether on which mode(32 or 64 bit)is java runtime version is running

Tags: 32bit-64bit, java

can you please please let me know how can I check whether on which mode (32 or 64 bit) my java runtime version is running.

Comment: Have a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807263/how-do-i-detect-which-kind-of-jre-is-installed-32bit-vs-64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JRE mode depends on the browser mode you are running. Check [this link](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml#verify%20browser) to know about your browser version. That will be the version of your browser JRE. Otherwise if you are using Windows 7 you can check it by going to control panel and look there for Java icon. It will be mentioned there. If you are using XP, most probably the version is 32 bit.

Comment: Thanks man, I am using Window server 2003, how can I know JRE version there as I don't have internet connection there, please suggest

Comment: I just looked your provided link, if I go to Internet Explorer Help->About, it is not giving any thing like "If version of IE displays 64-bit Edition, then it is 64-bit IE, otherwise it is a 32-bit browser."

Comment: check your system architecture by right clicking my computer and selecting properties. there it will be mentioned as 32 bit or 64 bit. If you are using 32 bit then no need to worry about 64 bit JRE. If you are using 64 bit then check if you are using 64 bit IE. If a 64 bit IE is installed on your machine then it will be named as Internet Explorer 64 Version.

Comment: If you are not using IE then you need not worry about 64 bit java.Did you check your control panel?

Comment: So you got your answer. Your Java environment is 32 Bit.